# Excel VBA: Selecting right cell when new column was added

Tags: excel, vba

Lets say in my Excel vba code I need a value of a cell. I do i.e the following:

```
Range("A" & row).Value
```

My Problem is, when I add a new column in the Excel sheet, the value I try to get is now in column B (because I created a new column A).

With

```
Range("A" & row).Value
```

I get empty value. How can I automatically get my right value, which is now in column B?

Comment: You could use headers for the columns. Or just name the columns. Then check for headers/column names to determine the right column

Comment: With the way you are doing it is always going to be set to `"A"`. What you can do is to have titles in the rows. Then use some VBA to check if the title matches the one you are looking for and get that column. Then use that column in the `range.value`

Comment: if you change it manually you can use `Range("A" & row + 1).Value`

Comment: @katz that would compensate new rows, but not new columns (what the author asked for)

Comment: @EngJon you're right: `Range(Columns(1) & row).Value` where 1 stands for column A

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to Range.Cells Property.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx

For example:
cells A1:C5

```
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 3))
```

And instead of numbers you can use variables like :

```
coulVar = 1
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, coulVar))
coulVar = coulVar + 1
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, coulVar))
```

or refer to one cell:

```
   Cells(1, coulVar).Value
```